# SQL Server on Ubuntu 18.04 Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, sqlcmd

I am trying to backup database on sql server with :`BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO  DISK = N'/path/to/file.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NOSKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10`

It creates backup if the path is `/var/opt/mssql/data/file.bak` cannot create backup in any other location. Is this a permission issue? Does any one had faced the same? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the group/user `mssql` have access to the folder?

Comment: chmod 777 applied. do i have to permit mssql also?

Comment: what's message you are getting when you try to backup at any other path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server on Linux (on Ubuntu) runs under the user `mssql`. If you want SQL Server to be able  to write to that folder, then either the user/group `mssql` needs write acces to the folder (and able to read/execute any parent folders), the `mssql` user needs to be part of a group that can, or the permissions for others needs to be set to write. Again, all parent folders need to allow access (read/execute).

If you had a Folder `/backups`, for example, owned by `root:` with the permissions `770`, and then a folder `/backups/SQLServer/` owned by `root:mssql` with the permission `775`, then SQL Server would be unable to write to the folder, as it wouldn't have been able to navigate to the folder `/backups`.